# Laptop running Ubuntu powers off randomly

Tags: ubuntu, power, zenbook

I have Asus Zenbook (UX305C) with Ubuntu 16.04 on it. The computer randomly powers off usually after a few hours. I was servicing it in an authorized Asus stand and they told me it is an OS issue. While using Windows 10, this behavior does not occur. It occurs without any particular reason. I do not do anything that might overheat the processor or something like that. Any ideas what could it be?

Comment: Does it really power off? Or does it only felt in sleep mode?

Comment: Yes. A if someone held power button for few seconds.